# C: pointers mixup

Tags: c, pointers, binaryfiles

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct{
        char cStdName[50];
        int  nStdNum;
        char cStdClass[4];
        float dStdAvg;
}student;

student* students;

int cmp(const void* a, const void* b);

void main() {
    int num = 0,i=0;
    FILE *f;

    printf("Number of students:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    students = (student*)malloc(num*sizeof(student));

    for(i=0;i<num;++i){

        student* ptr = students+i*sizeof(student);
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s", ptr->cStdName);
        printf("Num");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->nStdNum);
        printf("Class:");
        scanf("%s", ptr->cStdClass);
        printf("Grade:");
        scanf("%f", &ptr->dStdAvg);
    }

    f = fopen("bin.bin","wb");
    fwrite(&num,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(students,sizeof(student),num,f);
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
}
```

This is supposed to output the number of students and all the structure 'array' in a binary file and it works with 1 student. But when I add >=2 people, the file looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvXoA.png

If I add only 1 student, there is still some of this Windows path nonsense:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpfIZ.png
It is OK though, the program that reads the file ignores everything after the NULL(I mean, for the first char array).

I think the problem is somewhere in the for() loop and the pointer juggling but I can't tell where.

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: The "Windows path nonsense" is probably because you're allocating a fixed-size structure but not clearing it, and `scanf` doesn't know how big the array is.  Change `malloc(num*sizeof(student))` to `calloc(num, sizeof(student))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
student* ptr = students + i * sizeof(student);
```

In C, pointer arithmetic already includes `sizeof(student)`. You will read past the end of  your arrray.

```
student* ptr = students + i;
```

However, you'll notice accessing to `ptr` is the same as accessing to `students[i]`.

Comment: Or just use `students[i]`.

Comment: @Kirilenko
I thought of this but I implemented it in a slightly different way and it didn't work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

- First of all, as Kirilenko said, you should use `students[i]` in your code. In your case, `students + i * sizeof(student)` goes out of bounds.
- It's never a good idea to use `fwrite` with an array of structs. That's because the compiler may add some space between the members of a struct (padding), which means that when you pass an array of structs to `fwrite`, the padding bytes (which will contain garbage) will be printed.
- The same also applies to the char array members in your struct. All unused bytes will contain garbage, which will be printed when you use `fwrite`. It's better to use `strlen` to determine how many read characters each char array contains.

Here's how I'd write the students' array to a file:

```
void write(students* array, int len, FILE* out)
{
    int i;
    fwrite(len, 1, sizeof(len), out);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        fwrite(array[i]->cStdName, 1, strlen(array[i]->cStdName), out);
        fwrite(array[i]->nStdNum, 1, sizeof(array[i]->nStdNum), out);
        fwrite(array[i]->cStdClass, 1, strlen(array[i]->cStdClass), out);
        fwrite(array[i]->dStdAvg, 1, sizeof(array[i]->dStdAvg), out);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the point you're making, but can you please also show how to read your serialization back in?  It's not immediately obvious that it is possible to do so without ambiguity (I *think* you're fine because the strings are all NUL-terminated, but the code would clarify).  Also, maybe this function should be responsible for writing out the structure count as well.

Comment: ... actually I think you need `strlen(array[i]->cStdName) + 1` and similarly for `cStdClass`, for the NUL terminators to get written to disk.

Comment: That's true. I assumed that you didn't need to write the NUL terminators to your file.

Comment: If you don't write the terminators to the file, I think you can't read the file back in reliably; how do you know where the string fields end and the numeric fields begin?

Comment: @Zack Correct. I also added the structure count.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer assignment can be outside for loop once and you can increment the pointer at the end of for loop. Try this.

Ok. Here is an attempt to explain what is happening, the ptr is pointing to first element in students list of struct types and when you increment the ptr at the end of the for loop, it points to the next student in the list.

---

```
---
students = (student*)malloc(num*sizeof(student));
student* ptr = students;

    for(i=0;i<num;++i){

        printf("Name:");
        ----
        ----
        ptr++;
    }
```

Comment: This is fine and all, but for it to be a good answer, you should explain *why* it solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kirilenko's answer should solve your immediate problem, but there are errors ranging from trivial to severe on nearly every line of this program.  Depending on what your larger goal is, you might not need to fix all of them, but I'm going to write them all down anyway, to illustrate the size of the iceberg.

```
void main() {
```

`int main(void)`.  The `int` is an absolute requirement.  In C (not C++) writing `()` for a function argument list means the arguments are *unspecified*, not that there are no arguments; technically you can get away with it here because this is a function *definition*, but it's bad style.

The opening curly brace of a function definition always goes on a line by itself, even if all other opening braces are cuddled.

```
    int num = 0,i=0;
```

Inconsistent spacing.  Initializations are unnecessary.

```
    printf("Number of students:");
```

Some style guides prefer `fputs("Number of students", stdout);` when you're not using `printf`'s formatting capabilities.  But some compilers can do the transformation for you, and it's not a big deal.

```
    scanf("%d", &num);
```

**Never use `scanf`, `fscanf`, or `sscanf`**, because:

1. Numeric overflow triggers *undefined behavior*.  The C runtime is allowed to *crash your program* just because someone typed too many digits.
2. Some format specifiers (notably `%s`, which you use later in this program!) are unsafe in exactly the same way `gets` is unsafe, i.e. they will cheerfully write past the end of the provided buffer and crash your program (this particular program doesn't look security-sensitive to me, but one should always code as if one's programs are at least *somewhat* dangerous that way).
3. They make it extremely difficult to handle malformed input correctly.

The correct way to read a single nonnegative number from the user is like this:

```
unsigned long getul(void)
{
    char buf[80], *endp;
    unsigned long val;

    for (;;) {
        fgets(buf, 80, stdin);
        val = strtoul(buf, &endp, 10);
        if (endp != buf && *endp == '\n')
            return val;

        if (buf[strlen(buf)] != '\n')
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                /* discard */;
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Enter one nonnegative integer, smaller than %lu.\n",
                ULONG_MAX);
    }
}
```

You can get away with a fixed-size buffer here because nobody's ULONG_MAX is so large that it doesn't fit in 80 characters.

```
    students = (student*)malloc(num*sizeof(student));
```

You should use `calloc` here, so that when you go to write your structures to disk, they aren't full of junk.  (Or write custom serializers as suggested by Alexandros, that will also avoid the problem.)

```
    for(i=0;i<num;++i){
```

Preferred style is `for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {`.  In addition to the spacing, use `i++` instead of `++i` so that `i` appears in the same position in all three expressions; this makes it easier to read.

```
        student* ptr = students+i*sizeof(student);
```

`student* ptr = students + i;` as discussed elsewhere.

```
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s", ptr->cStdName);
```

See comments above.  You want another helper function, like so:

```
void getstr(char *buf, size_t len)
{
    size_t n;

    for (;;) {
        fgets(buf, len, stdin);
        n = strlen(buf);
        if (n < len && buf[n] == '\n') {
            memset(buf+n, 0, len-n);
            return;
        }
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            /* discard */;
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Enter no more than %lu characters.",
                (unsigned long)(len-1));
    }
}
```

...

```
        scanf("%f", &ptr->dStdAvg);
```

And here you need another helper function. `getf` is exactly the same as `getul` except it uses `strtod`, and of course the error message is a little different.

```
    f = fopen("bin.bin","wb");
```

Isn't that an awfully generic file name?  There should probably be a way for the user to specify it.

```
    fwrite(&num,sizeof(int),1,f);
```

Your file format needs a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Internal_metadata).

```
    fwrite(students,sizeof(student),num,f);
```

You are writing binary data to disk in CPU-endian order.  That may not be a problem for this application, but be aware that you might have a cross-platform compatibility headache down the road.  (Personally, for what it looks like you're doing, I would use a textual serialization such as JSON, or a simple no-daemon database such as sqlite.)  See Alexandros' answer for more potential problems with this file format.

It's rarely a problem when writing to files on disk, and this isn't the sort of program whose output gets piped somewhere, but still, I'm'a mention that `fwrite` does not guarantee to write all the data you provide it.  Technically you have to call `fwrite` in a loop like this:

```
size_t r, n = sizeof(student) * num;
char *p = (char *)students;
while (n > 0) {
    r = fwrite(p, 1, n, f);
    if (r == 0) break;  /* write error */
    n -= r;
    p += r;
}
```

For this to work correctly you *must* do the multiplication yourself and pass 1 for the second argument to `fwrite`; otherwise a short write may end in the middle of an "element of data" and you have no way of knowing that this has happened.

```
    fclose(f);
```

Check for write errors before closing the file.

```
if (ferror(f) || fclose(f)) {
    perror("bin.bin");
    return 1; /* unsuccessful exit */
}
```

...

```
    system("pause");
```

Just `return 0`.  Programs that make you hit a key to exit are batch-unfriendly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort of writing such a lengthy post, covering much more than my question. You have a point about a lot of things but some are a bit nitpicky for a boring school assignments and others (like the opening bracket) are just personal preference. But thanks again!